# How to register promises in foreach and resolve all?

Tags: javascript, foreach, promise

I'm trouble with promises and foreach. I want to inside a foreach register promises and after resolving all promises execute some code.

I already tried async/await but do not solve my problem because every call function must be async so I believe that it will be solved with a promise

//Original Code.

```
async function (rotamed) {

console.log("Before.")

clientes.forEach(c => {
        fc_paciente(rotamed,c)
        fc_servico(rotamed,c)
        especialidades.forEach(esp => {
            fc_profissional(rotamed,c,esp)
        })
    })

    console.log("After.")

}
```

Try to resolve with promise:

```
async function (rotamed) {
console.log("Before.")
let promises = []
clientes.forEach(c => {
                    promises.push(new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                        fc_paciente(rotamed,c)
                    }))
})
console.log(promises)

Promise.all(promises).then((x) => console.log("After"))

}
```

Every call function fc_paciente, fc_servico, and fc_profissional must be async and when all resolve then I call console.log("After").

Comment: Your `new Promise` doesn't get resolved?

Comment: `async` keyword is useless if you don't use `await`.

Comment: @Hodrobond, where I should insert a resolve, inside the fc_paciente? This promise will be resolved when the fc_paciente finish.

Comment: `This promise will be resolved when the fc_paciente finish` - that sounds like `fc_paciente(rotamed,c).then(resolve).catch(reject)`

Comment: @trincot yes, I forgot to remove, I was trying with await

Comment: What do those functions like `fc_paciente` return? A promise?

Comment: @trincot no. Without a return, I trying now return a promise.

Comment: @trincot and Hodrobond i mixed yours advice and it's worked !! I'm learning JS. I forgot to return a promise and function fc_paciente must be resolved as a new promise.

Answer (score 0):

The fc_pacientes must return a Promise with resolve() and

```
clientes.forEach(c => {
                        promises.push(new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
                            fc_paciente(rotamed,c).then(resolve).catch(reject)
                        }))
```

Thanks for comments.